# Android layout border shape with cut corners

Tags: android

i want layout like this on xml [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jyx8.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp">
    </corners>
    <solid
        android:color="#fefefe">
    </solid>
    <padding
        android:left="15dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#e3e3e3"/>
</shape>
```

always try to change to cut corners but i can not do it

Answer (score 2):

For cut corner, you need to use `ShapeAppearance` [Shape Theming](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/theming/shape)

**1. In styles.xml, create your shape**

```
<style name="YourComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">Your cut size</item>
</style>
```

**2. In your layout, use a `CardView` as it root**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentPadding="10dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/YourComponent">
    
    // Your content goes here

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]